# How to fetch string from html with <a></a> tags?

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, nsstring

I am having string like following.

```
<a href=\"http://www.google.com\" title=\"My Title\" target=\"_blank\">Link 1</a>
```

How will i get "href" and "Link1" substrings.
I have tried,but i didn't get valid solution.Please share the solution.Thanks in advance.

Comment: `"I have tried,but i didn't get valid solution"` What have you tried? Please share everything you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For fetching the URL from a string:

```
NSRegularExpression *expression = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(?i)\\b((?:[a-z][\\w-]+:(?:/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|www\\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)(?:[^\\s()<>]+|\\(([^\\s()<>]+|(\\([^\\s()<>]+\\)))*\\))+(?:\\(([^\\s()<>]+|(\\([^\\s()<>]+\\)))*\\)|[^\\s`!()\\[\\]{};:'\".,<>?«»“”‘’]))" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:NULL];

NSString *someString = @"<a href=\"http://www.google.com\" title=\"My Title\" target=\"_blank\">Link 1</a>";

NSString *match = [someString substringWithRange:[expression rangeOfFirstMatchInString:someString options:NSMatchingCompleted range:NSMakeRange(0, [someString length])]];

NSLog(@"%@", match); // Correctly prints 'http://www.google.com'
```

for matching the text:

```
   NSRegularExpression *textRegex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\>([^]]+)\<" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:NULL];

NSString *someString = @"<a href=\"http://www.google.com\" title=\"My Title\" target=\"_blank\">Link 1</a>";

    NSString *match = [someString substringWithRange:[expression rangeOfFirstMatchInString:someString options:NSMatchingCompleted range:NSMakeRange(0, [someString length])]];

   NSLog(@"%@", match); // Correctly prints 'Link 1'
```

Hope you will be able to use it now

Comment: I have updated the answer. Please check it now. Hope its useful to you

Comment: Please mark it as answer if it has resolved your issue